# I need to add JBoss tools to my Eclipse but I am using springtoolsuite (STS)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jboss

I need to add JBoss tools to my Eclipse but I am using springtoolsuite (STS).

How can I find the Eclipse version name that Spring tool Suite STS is using.. I need to add JBoss tools to it and I dont know which one I am using

Comment: Which STS Version do you use?

Comment: Zip up your STS before you try and add JBoss tools.  That way, if you encounter a problem installing the JBoss tools, you can unzip a known good working version of STS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Look at

`Help/About SpringSource Tool Suite/` click on the `Eclipse.org` sybol